# Using AJAX and PHP to create a realtime search of server side files

Tags: php, ajax, file, search

I am new to PHP and Ajax. I want to create a create a realtime searchbox on my page that will search the meta tag keywords of all html pages on my server and generate a list of links for files that match.

Does this seem like a viable option? Or will it be too slow as it will use scandir to get the list of html, then extract the meta tag from each file in the list and find matches? The site may eventually grow to several hundred pages so number of files is an issue but I am not sure how fast Ajax and PHP will be.

Also, the ideal situation would be a partial match of keywords so 'in' would match both insect and international.

Comment: You mean  a 'autocomplete'?  That is usually a pre-generated list.  Do you have all the meta tag keywords separately in the database? then you can easily do it realtime. If you want to search through full webpages in the database first then it would probably be too slow (and highly inefficient).  http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step

Comment: For the most performant solution, you need to hand over the job to a tool that is designed for searching file contents. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40773407/65732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax would be fast enough, as would PHP, I have done this before,

But to comment on your concept.

I would use a sql database such as mysql to actually perform the search as opposed to using scandir and then opening every page (and then scanning for the meta tag. ) which I assume would involve you then further parsing files on your page.

The search code would be much much simpler, and execute an order of magnitude faster. especially with multiple users forcing your code to call scandir at the same time ( disk access is always the slowest form of IO. )

you could then write a php script which could perform your 'scandir' method and then update the database.

in addition to this you could then also have the option of dumping your 'meta tag table' via JSON and performing the search completely on the client side in the future.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, I have zero familiarity with JSON and I have just started learning Ajax. Other than readability of object data definition I don't see the advantage of JSON vs. using XmlHtmlRequestObject. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: XmlHttpRequest is simply the transport medium, the method of encoding the data inside is a separate issue, JSON is extremely simple to use auto-magically (php's json_encode / json_decode commands) and javascript will treat the returned data as arrays/objects instantly (which is also beneficial) because it reduces your development time significantly and increases your code readability. 

Using XML as a content encoding is both harder to encode and decode